# Php / Pdo statement gives "0"

Tags: php, pdo, crypt

i am using ipn from paypal, this is how i send data to paypal:

```
require_once 'classes/Crypt.php';

$crypt = new Crypt();
$crypt->Mode = Crypt::MODE_HEX;
$crypt->Key  = '§$TERGERG§$T§34t';

$test = array('cmd'=>'_xclick',
                'business'=>'meine_email',
                'notify_url'=> 'url_zum_ipn',
                'item_name'=>'name',
                'amount'=>'1.00',
                'currency_code'=>'USD',
                'lc'=>'US',
                'custom'=>$crypt->encrypt(serialize(array("username" => $username))));

                $url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?".http_build_query($test);
                header("Location:".$url);
                exit();
```

this is how i process data in my ipn script:

```
require_once '../classes/Crypt.php';

$crypt = new Crypt();
$crypt->Mode = Crypt::MODE_HEX;
$crypt->Key  = '§$TERGERG§$T§34t';

$custom = unserialize($crypt->decrypt($_POST["custom"]));

$username = $custom['username'];

try
{
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO products (product_name)
                                    VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $value1);

    $value1 = $username;

    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    $body .= "Error: " . $exception->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

There is no insert in my table, but this message:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
'product_name' cannot be null
```

I check if the variable $username is send in the beginning, it is!
But when i check the variable $username in the ipn-script with this:

```
if($username == "") { // gives true
```

So anybody knows where is my wrong code? greetings!

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO products (product_name)
                                VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value1);

$value1 = $username;

$stmt->execute();
```

With:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO products(product_name) VALUES(:productName)");
$stmt->execute([':productName' => $username]);
```

Comment: yeah but why this part gives true? : if ($username == "")